# Build a Google Workspace Add-on in any coding language that works on mobile

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I've built two Google Workspace addons for testing, one in apps script and one using my own backend server returning JSON (per https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes)

The one I created in apps script appears in my Gmail iOS app, but the one I created with my own language returning JSON does not.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or is this a tradeoff of using your own backend server instead of apps script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously, an alternate runtime (utilizing our own language) for the UI Kit on Gmail for iOS was not accessible. However, I wanted to inform you that this feature is now available.

I've received an email from Google recently regarding this. here the email:

> Following the roll-out of the new UI Kit for Gmail on Android and
> others, the UI Kit for Gmail on iOS has just been made available to
> the members of the Developer Preview Program. In addition, alternate
> runtime Add-ons are now supported on iOS.
>
> Only the members of the Developer Preview Program see the updated
> version of add-ons (*allowlisting in this case is done with your email
> account, not your Google Cloud project). If a colleague of yours is
> not in the program, they won’t see the change, nor do your customers.
> Please note that additional style changes might be seen in future due
> to our effort to adopt the UI to Material 3 guidelines.

As it's currently exclusive to the Developer Preview Program, you can access it by joining [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/preview) if you haven't already.